# Laravel / Artisan CLI resets error_reporting level?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

We are using the Laravel job queue to run several jobs through the schedule:run cron.  We have error reporting in our php.ini (for apache as well as for the command line) set to suppress PHP's deprecated errors, yet it seems the jobs are not completing successfully.

When I try to run the jobs manually at the command line through artisan I get deprecation errors, so I suspect this is what's causing them to fail.

If I add:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', 'E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED');
```

to the top of the job's php file it works successfully when called manually and when run on the job schedule.

Is Artisan resetting the error reporting level somehow or discarding the error level set by the php.ini file?

I've run

```
php -r "echo error_reporting();"
```

at the command line and it shows me the correct error reporting integer to indicate that deprecated errors should be suppressed.

Comment: Don't quote `'E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED'`, they're each separate constants. You're basically turning off all errors now.

Comment: the ini_set method takes two strings, I think this is how you're supposed to do it.  The error_reporting value is not quoted in the ini file.

Comment: See [`error_reporting()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

Comment: [ini_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) can't really be used this way then it seems - at least not with a complex error_reporting setting.  I'm sure you could do ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL).  Either way, I don't want to do this ini setting at all.  I'm not concerned with whether I'm suppressing only deprecated errors or all errors.

Comment: `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);` [works just fine](https://3v4l.org/pBAcJ).

Comment: You can setup crontab to run as `www-data` user, look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/210545/750660)

Comment: It's very strange to me that that works.  It looks like PHP has special handling in place for those constants?  I can't define my own and use & and ~ to add (and subtract) them.

What does running the crontab as www-data do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've found that Laravel is overriding the error_reporting setting in: vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php

```
public function bootstrap(Application $app)
{
    $this->app = $app;

    error_reporting(-1);

    set_error_handler([$this, 'handleError']);

    set_exception_handler([$this, 'handleException']);

    register_shutdown_function([$this, 'handleShutdown']);

    if (! $app->environment('testing')) {
        ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');
    }
}
```

By removing the error_reporting(-1); line here Laravel respects the system's error_reporting setting in php.ini.  Obviously this prevents Laravel from capturing and reporting errors that are suppressed through system configuration - which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Modifying a file in `vendor` is NEVER what you want.